# htacces url rewrite not working, pls help resolve

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a html login page and I want to restrict direct access to the html page or redirect to my login page every time an html page is accessed directly in browser. 
So I used the below entry in .htaccess, but its not working. Im using Apache 2.4.6

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?10.26.104.37 [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?10.26.104.37.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule \.(html)$ - [F]

<Directory "<doc path">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your apachemu configuration file in apache2.conf